# How to update table from spatial query

Tags: sql-server-2008, spatial

I have two tables, A and B, in SQL Server 2008:

```
A
lon(float)
lat(float)
name (nvarchar)

B
name (nvarchar)
the_geom (geometry)
```

Basically table B contains area polygons, and table A contains point coordinates in two columns. I want to update table A with the area name, if the point defined in lon/lat columns is inside a polygon in table B. What is the correct T-SQL command? This is my unsuccessful query so far:

```
UPDATE A SET name = (SELECT name FROM B WHERE
the_geom.STIntersects(geography::Point([A.lat], [A.Lon], 4326))>0)
```

Comment: Im assuming that you have checked that the 2 tables do intersect...

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
UPDATE Deals SET Area = (
    SELECT NAME FROM Areas WHERE 
        the_geom.STIntersects(
            geometry::STGeomFromText(
                'POINT(' + CAST(Deals.Lon AS varchar) + ' ' + CAST(Deals.Lat AS varchar) + ')',4326)
                ) = 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be you are mixing spatial types and x / y. (Geometry and Geography are different).

You could write your query as:

```
UPDATE A SET name = (SELECT name FROM B WHERE 
    the_geom.STIntersects(
          geometry::STPointFromText(
               'POINT(' + [A.long] + ' ' + [A.lat] + ')', 4326
          )
    )=1)
```

Haven't actually tried the above but it should give all you need to solve the issue. If you want to continue using Geography then you could also create as you do, revert it to WKB and then into a geometry instance via WKB (geometry::STGeomFromWKB(geography::AsBinary())

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I am getting Invalid column name 'a.Lon', even though the table has this column

Comment: I doesn't sound that it is a spatial issue you are facing... If you can post the table creation scripts and I will put together the query

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Areas](
 [gid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [NAME] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
 [the_geom] [geometry] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_export_attiki] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [gid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Deals](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Lon] [float] NULL,
 [Lat] [float] NULL,
 [Area] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Deals] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: This is the query that fails:

UPDATE deals SET area = (SELECT name FROM areas WHERE 
    the_geom.STIntersects(
          geometry::STPointFromText(
               'POINT(' + [A.lon] + ' ' + [A.lat] + ')', 4326
          )
    )=1)

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like 'dahh', but shouldn't you use deals.lon instead of A.lon?

UPDATE deals SET area = (SELECT name FROM areas WHERE the_geom.STIntersects( geometry::STPointFromText( 'POINT(' + [deals].[lon] + ' ' + [deals].[lat] + ')', 4326 ) )=1)

Comment: Well spotted, but it still gives me the same error. It seems to me that the correlated subquery fails to resolve the outer table because it is inside the STPointFromText function.